Some fonts rendering too thin in various contexts (Sonoma)
Macbook Pro M1 Max running Sonoma.
Lately, some fonts render way too thin ... in Chrome, Mail, etc. Looks terrible.
Here are some examples:
Mail.app:

Chrome:


Can you open the inspector and post the font used and font attributes like variant, family, weight? It is indeed a problem sometimes safari renders text different from chrome. It's likely about interpretations of font-weight.
